# create user in hippo cms using rest api

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

I am able to create users using hippo cms login.
I want to create the users withou using the hipppo cms console.
Instead for example would be using rest apis to create hippo users.
How can i achieve these. 
Are there any api given by hippo to create users.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer provided on our mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/hippo-community/wLZeoMJHJXo/discussion